# What am I doing wrong while sending the form data with file

Tags: angular

In the below version I am sending the data. The file doesn't get sent.

[image: When I console.log data]

```
onSubmit() {
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('resume', this.chosenFile);
    const data = this.contactForm.value;
    data['resume'] = fd;
    console.log(data);
    this.loading = true;
    this.data.createJobEnquiry(data).subscribe((res)=>{
      this.loading = false; 
    },(err)=>{
      this.loading = false; 
      console.log(err)
      alert("Something went wrong");
    });
  }
```

In the below code I am only sending the fd which is the file and it gets sent.

```
onSubmit() {
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('resume', this.chosenFile);
    this.loading = true;
    this.data.createJobEnquiry(fd).subscribe((res)=>{
      this.loading = false; 
    },(err)=>{
      this.loading = false; 
      console.log(err)
      alert("Something went wrong");
    });
  }
```

HTML:

```
 <input formControlName="resume" type="file" id="real-file" (change)="onFileSelected($event)" style="display: none;">
```

How I am getting the file. I am getting the file correctly so no problem there.

```
onFileSelected(event) {
  this.chosenFile = <File>event.target.files[0];
}
```

In the first one it gives the error "Resume is required" so its not being sent at all, in the second one no error the file is sent correctly error cant be in the service. It error is in the way I am assigning the resume field the file.

`this.contactForm.value` is the object which contains all the form data including the resume filed which initially just has the file path.
Here data['resume'] = fd; I am just assigning the file to that resume field. I know the error is somewhere there I might not be doing it correctly.
If i hard code `data['resume'] = "dd"` the error from the server is only pdf file allowed, which further establishes that I am not sending the file correctly when using data.

Comment: So what is the question here? and how this `createJobEnquiry()` method looks like? any error in the console? is that API is called from Postman?

Comment: post your service function code here

Comment: In the first one it gives the error "Resume is required" so its not being sent correctly, in the second one no error.

Comment: `createJobEnquiry(formDetails: any) {
        return this.http.post(this.createJobInquiryApi, formDetails);
      }`

Comment: @zuyi is that API is called from Postman?

Comment: both post man and angular

Comment: the problem is that you cant send form data in json object. I am still looking for solution

Comment: @zuyi can you post the screen of postman that how u are sending requests?

Comment: @zuyi Nothing wrong in your code, try checking the file is successfully uploaded at the server end/

Comment: @zuyi and at what basis you are uploading file i.e userId? CustomerId which is uploading the data?